# I keep getting the "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s) error

Tags: asp.net, powershell, docker, dockerfile

First of, I am trying to follow along with this [guide](http://fluentbytes.com/deploying-asp-net-4-5-to-docker-on-windows/).

So far I have the host up and running, but I am stuck at this one point. I've installed the windowsservercore image, and I installed the IIS image and tagged it 'windowsserveriis'. Now I need to install ASP.NET 4.5, and I use the following command

> docker build –t windowsserveriisaspnet .

I should maybe add that I create a folder for my Docker images. So I have a C:\dev\TestProject\DockerImages and the a folder for each Dockerfile. Now, I am a bit unsure about this, as the guide never mentions how to actually create the files, so I thought I would divide them up just to be safe (and also be able to have them be named just 'Dockerfile' to avoid confusion).

Anyways, the above command prints out the following error message:

> docker : "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
>
> At line:1 char:1
>
> docker build –t windowsserveriisaspnet .

My Dockerfile looks like this:

> FROM windowsserveriis
>
> RUN dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-ASPNET45

My initial thought was that i forgot the dot at the end, but that is not the case. I also tried replacing the dot with '--file="DockerfileASPNET"' (where I renamed the file). However nothing seems to work.

So, what am I missing? Thanks in advance..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help

Comment: @alldani He already has the `.` in his code so that answer is not relevant.  @kasper where are you running the command from?  are you inside the folder you created to house the Dockerfile?  Also make sure your Dockerfile is named `Dockerfile` with correct capitalization

Comment: But that doesn't really answer my question. Like I said, I already checked for a missing dot.

Comment: There are more answers. Also, you should google it, and if you tried that question, you should mention it. It will save everyone time, as you can now tell.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio I cd'ed to the right folder and just ran the command with the dot in there.

Comment: @alldani what the hell? It worked if I typed it manually.. But they're identical (well obviously not).

Comment: @alldani my apologies, I didn't see the second answer.

Comment: No problem. Let's keep it PG.

Comment: Sure thing, I was just amazed that this was the issue. Anyways I actually looked at that question, but I didn't see the second answer.

Comment: For me, I was using the --build-arg option, and I was getting this error. I put quotes around my value and that fixed it... It now is `run: docker build --build-arg SECRET="${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}" --tag myRepo/myImage:myTag .`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out there was some hidden formatting in my command. If I wrote it out manually, instead of copy/pasting, it worked. So I guess the lesson learned here is; check your copying.

Comment: After trying everything, the only thing that worked for me in Powershell was typing it out

Answer (score 34):

I was facing the same issue. I missed the little period ( . ) at the end of the command. 
I copy pasted the command from official docker docs.
The period
( . ) at the end of the command tells Docker to use the shell’s current working
directory as the build context.
Be sure include the period (.) at the end of the command, and be sure to run the
command from the current working directory that contains the Dockerfile and application code.

Comment: And don't forget to include the period (.) at the end ;)

Comment: NUB mistake! LOL! (I did the same!)

Comment: Yes but it's not only (.) at the end but a space and (.) at the end worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

Docker build requires docker file.

***Note***: you must provide URL or path where you store your built docker image file. You missed providing the URL or path

**SYNTAX**: `docker image build OPTIONS <url or path>`

Solution commands (in 2 ways)

1. `docker image build -f <dockerfile> <url or path>`
2. `docker build -f <dockerfile> <url or path>`

Eg, `docker build --file ./Dockerfile.txt .`

Answer (score 5):

I have also faced the same issue when I copy pasted the given command. However, it worked when I typed the same command given below.

```
$ docker image build -t python-hello-world .
```

Comment: You should try including why it works like this if you want your answer to be more helpful in the future. 

Also, you can put commands in a code block in the editor so it formats nicely.

Answer (score 2):

If .Dockerfile is in your current directory use:

docker build –t windowsserveriisaspnet -f ./.Dockerfile .

So you point to the specific file -f ./.Dockerfile and need to point to local folder using . (dot at the end).

Answer (score 1):

Try in this format

```
docker build --pull -t windowsserver . -f <path where dockerfile is present>
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically i used to think that using switch -f or --file, it does not require the additional input of Dockerfile Path. But it requires it at the end.So cmd should be

"$docker build --tag REPO-NAME:TAG-NAME --file FILEPATH DIRPATH

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing the (copy&paste) error hasn't been recorded here - the error is in the em/en dash character.

One of these commands is wrong.

This has the wrong char i.e. –

> docker build –t windowsserveriisaspnet .

While this has the correct one i.e. -

> docker build -t windowsserveriisaspnet .

Answer (score 0):

For me inspecting label values gave the answer. Some of the values contained a space character. Putting that value between " " solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and the problem was that I missed the . at the end.

docker image build -t repo/learn:23 .

It basically points to the current working directory. so now it know from where to pick the Dockerfile

Comment: The question states that the . was included at the end