# docker can't stat directory on external device

Tags: linux, docker

## Briefly

I'm looking to build docker image from a dockerfile in a directory on an external device.

## Context

- I have an empty directory `/media/nathan/ext/test` except for Dockerfile
- Dockerfile is : `FROM alpine`
- docker version is : `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d28e`
- OS is Ubuntu 21.10
- I am part of the `docker` group
- mount options :

```
$> findmnt /media/nathan/ext
TARGET            SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/nathan/ext /dev/sda1 ext4   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime
```

- docker deamon

```
$> ps aux | grep dockerd
root         919  0.0  0.5 2166356 85600 ?       Ssl  09:03   0:08 dockerd --group docker --exec-root=/run/snap.docker --data-root=/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker --pidfile=/run/snap.docker/docker.pid --config-file=/var/snap/docker/1125/config/daemon.json
nathan     19756  0.0  0.0  11844  2448 pts/0    S+   11:44   0:00 grep --color=auto dockerd
```

- `$DOCKER_HOST` is undefined

```
$> echo $DOCKER_HOST
```

## docker info

```
$> docker info 
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
 Containers: 1
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 1
 Images: 263
 Server Version: 20.10.8
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: e25210fe30a0a703442421b0f60afac609f950a3
 runc version: 
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
```

## Expected result

I get a docker image

## True result

```
$> docker build .
error checking context: 'can't stat '/media/nathan/ext/test''.
```

## What I have tried

### Just `sudo` everything

```
$> sudo docker build .
error checking context: 'can't stat '/media/nathan/ext/test''.
```

Issue is not resolved

### [Am I the owner of the context folder ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286028/docker-build-error-checking-context-cant-stat-c-users-username-appdata)

```
$> echo $USER
nathan

$> ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 nathan nathan 4096 nov.  12 10:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 nathan root   4096 nov.  12 09:39 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nathan nathan   12 nov.  12 10:32 Dockerfile
```

As per command above, I am the owner of the context directory. Am I missing something ?

### [add everything to .dockerignore](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/380)

I've created a `.dockerignore` that matches everything : '*'.
Running the command `[sudo] docker build .` gives a very baffling answer:

```
$> sudo docker build .
open /media/nathan/ext/test/.dockerignore: permission denied
```

I do not understand how sudo doesn't have the necessary permissions to read (?) the `.dockerfile`. Permission which I have set to 777 out of astonishement :

```
 ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 nathan nathan 4096 nov.  12 10:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 nathan root   4096 nov.  12 09:39 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nathan nathan   12 nov.  12 10:32 Dockerfile
-rwxrwxrwx 1 nathan nathan    2 nov.  12 10:41 .dockerignore
```

of course, other programms were capable of reading the file without any issue as expected

```
$> cat .dockerignore 
*
```

### Build outside of external drive

```
$> pwd
/home/nathan/Bureau/test

$> ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 nathan nathan 4096 nov.  12 10:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 nathan nathan 4096 nov.  12 10:56 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 nathan nathan   12 nov.  12 10:58 Dockerfile

$> docker build .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/1 : FROM alpine
 ---> 14119a10abf4
Successfully built 14119a10abf4
```

Image is built, but I which to replicate result into external drive.

### running `docker build .` with journalctl

```
[...]

nov. 12 11:42:52 nathan-pc systemd[1746]: Started snap.docker.docker.ba3da9ef-34ee-4a63-8ff4-6a56327c5cd2.scope.
nov. 12 11:42:52 nathan-pc audit[19690]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.docker" name="/media/nathan/ext/workspace/dino/ntrip-client/RTKLIB/" pid=19690 comm="docker" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
nov. 12 11:42:52 nathan-pc kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1636713772.367:93): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.docker" name="/media/nathan/ext/workspace/dino/ntrip-client/RTKLIB/" pid=19690 comm="docker" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000
nov. 12 11:42:52 nathan-pc systemd[1746]: snap.docker.docker.ba3da9ef-34ee-4a63-8ff4-6a56327c5cd2.scope: Deactivated successfully.

[...]
```

## Thank you for your time

Comment: How is the external device mounted? What are the mount options? Aaaanyway, just `docker build - < Dockerfile`.

Comment: Thank you @KamilCuk , this seems to work. Would you kindly explain why this works unlike `docker build .` ? I'm very confused of why passing by stdin works better.

Comment: `docker build .` uses `.` directory as build context, `docker build -` has no build context - and you can research what is "docker build context" online. In your case, `.` can't be `mount -o bind`, which leads to the question how is `.` mounted.

Comment: It is mounted at startup, do you need my `etc/fstab` ? Or else, what command do you want me to run ? Thank you for your patience and help.

Comment: I think `findmnt /media/nathan/ext` or `mount | grep ext`. What is it, is it a SD card, external hdd, etc...? It's mounted from `/etc/fstab` by you manually? Does anything come up in syslog (`journalctl -fa` + run `docker build .` + see what comes up)? `ext4   rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime` that looks totally fine... `open /media/nathan/ext/test/.dockerignore: permission denied` What would `ps aux | grep dockerd` output? What user executed `dockerd` daemon? What is the value of `$DOCKER_HOST` or are you connecting to any remote docker? What is `docker info` output?

Comment: my question as been updated with requested information. It's an external HDD. If I remember well, I have updated the fstab manually but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 21.10. Please, give me a moment to do everything you've asked me to do.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I think I've added everything you asked. Should we moved this discussion to chat ?

Comment: Well, `AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.docker.docker"` is quite clear ;)

Comment: I'm sorry if I appear "noobish" but it is no yet clear to me. What is `AVC apparmor` and why it has denied the docker request of opening the dockerfile. From a little research, It appears that the issue was snap but I don't fully understand why. I've reinstall docker through apt and it is working as expected. If you feel like it, would you mind writing a proper answer to the question for futur users ? If you don't want to, I will do it myself, but it will surely be of a lower quality as I'm still confuse of what the problem was.