# docker build - exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I've been trying to build syntaxnet on my ubuntu setup and bumped into a problem (simple as it may be) that I had hard time finding the solution to.

Whenever I try to build using the command:

```
docker build -t dragnn-oss:latest-minimal -f docker-devel/Dockerile.min
```

I get the error message:

```
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).
```

Now, my docker version is 17.06 and according to this page, 
[[docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help][1]), I should be able to specify a Dockerfile that is located in a different directory, so I don't see what the problem is.

Edit: I created a symlink by doing:

```
ln -s docker-devel/Dockerfile.min link1
```

Then I just went through with the command:

```
docker build -t dragnn-oss:latest-minimal -f link1 .
```

and it worked.

I thought I did not need to put the . at the end since I specified the Dockerfile with -f but learned the mistake.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a dot at the end, either

`docker build -t mytag .`

or

`docker build -t dragnn-oss:latest-minimal -f docker-devel/Dockerile.min .`

see also

[docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help/28997256#28997256)

Comment: Putting a . at the end gives me unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: error.

Comment: I have updated my answer, you need to specify the path of the Dockerfile, followed by a dot. The dot specifies the context of the build.

Comment: I've forgot to mention that I've tried to put the . before but resulted in the above-mentioned error. I guess I'll look further into that specific error message.

Comment: I think I might have solved the problem simply by creating a symlink. and using that instead of the directory path. Thank you for clearing my head to see the mistake.

Comment: The dot must be at the end, you can do either `docker build .` or the 2 other examples I posted

Comment: Yeap. My immediate interpretation to the docker build's argument for path was that --file specification is enough but after going over what the PATH dictates, I've realized that the . is always necessary. Which begs the question why the syntaxnet's command input didn't specify a symlink or the . at the end.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers are all correct and you've found the solution, I want to point you to the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) for `docker build` for anyone stumbling upon this. This is what the command is supposed to look like:

```
$ docker build [OPTIONS] PATH
```

In your example, you specified two options (`-f` and `-t`). But you didn't specify the `PATH` argument. Citing the documentation:

> The `PATH` specifies where to find the files for the “context” of the build on the Docker daemon.

The context is sent to the Docker daemon when building an image. You can just use `.` if you want to use the correct directory as Docker's build context, but as others have mentioned, you can also specify a specific directory, e.g. `docker-devel`.

Comment: Yea, I read the documentation and the part that I got confused over was the PATH. Because "Dockerfile.min" isn't a default of "Dockerfile", I imagined that it would be sufficient with me specifying the exact file path. However, I learned my lesson that it isn't. I'm just getting into this, so all the help are very appreciated.

Comment: Also, always create a specific directory for your stuff, if you put your Dockerfile in /home/$USER, and you have many huge videos files, `docker build` will display for a looong time, as docker build tars up your current working directory (or the folder containing the dockerfile) and uploads it to the Docker Daemon for the build steps.if you see `Sending build context to docker daemon` followed by `234 GB` or such, you know something is wrong

Comment: The `PATH` is not about the Dockerfile, but the **build context**. This is what @user2915097 is talking about. The path you specify is the directory that is sent to the Docker daemon for building the image. In your Dockerfile, you are limited to the build context, and cannot access any files outside of it. This is why you need to specify both the Dockerfile (instructions) as well as the context (resources). Only with those two, Docker is able to build an image.

Comment: Yea, thanks for clarifying that. Now I understand that portion completely. Makes a lot of sense when you put it that way. I was too focused on the fact that in the most simplistic command" `docker build .`  there is no Dockerfile and `.` is used that I did not take a second to really think about the meaning of it all. My bad. And thanks for the clear cut explanations. I was able to build properly using the help. So cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Specify a directory and in this directory, a Dockerfile :

```
docker build -t dragnn-oss:latest-minimal -f Dockerile.min docker-devel
```

Comment: I am following the guide here. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet/docker-devel The docker-devel is the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an argument to the end with just the path.
If it's the current directory then `.` (simple dot) will suffice.
The `-f` param is just for the filename (Dockerfile being the default)

```
docker build -t dragnn-oss:latest-minimal -f Dockerile.min docker-devel
```

Comment: I am specifying the exact location to be "docker-devel/Dockerfile.min"

Comment: Yes, that is incorrect. For the -f parameter you specify just the name of your Dockerfile. The argument at the end of the command is then the path to your build root. You shouldn't use the full path, just the directory. Have you tried to copy paste the suggestion above? If so what is the result?

Comment: When I tried your suggestion, I got an error saying there is no Dockerfile.min at the current working directory level. I thus had to do "-f docker-devel/Dockerfile.min ."  And it worked. From what I'm getting, seems like docker is able to take in a full path too.