# Jenkins Pipeline docker.build() gives error '"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s)'

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

With this minimal Jenkins Pipeline script

```
node {
  docker.build("foo", "--build-arg x=y")
}
```

I'm getting a confusing error

> "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument(s).

But as per the documentation, the signature of `docker.build()` is `build(image[, args])` (from Jenkins `/job/dockerbug/pipeline-syntax/globals#docker`)

> `build(image[, args])`
>
> Runs docker build to create and tag the specified
>   image from a Dockerfile in the current directory. Additional args may
>   be added, such as `'-f Dockerfile.other --pull --build-arg
>   http_proxy=http://192.168.1.1:3128 .'`. Like docker build, args must
>   end with the build context. Returns the resulting Image object.
>   Records a FROM fingerprint in the build.

What's going on?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

My confusion was because the error message is actually coming from Docker, not Jenkins.

Docker gives this error if you don't specify a build context (as noted in the docs above).

The fix is just to add `.` to the end of the args parameter as per the example, eg:

```
node {
  docker.build("foo", "--build-arg x=y .")
}
```

See [docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help)

Comment: After days of searching I finally found it!

Thanks

Comment: Be aware of this issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41395