# Jenkins pipeline docker build not working

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I did my research and based on the links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45998130/jenkins-pipeline-docker-build-gives-error-docker-build-requires-exactly-1-a#:%7E:text=%22docker%20build%22%20requires%20exactly%201%20argument(s).&text=Runs%20docker%20build%20to%20create,%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.1%3A3128%20.) and [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) I would assume that running this command `docker.build("tas/tuya-message-listener-china:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}", "--build-arg jar=tuya-message-listener-ecs-china.jar .")` would have worked, but what I get is this in the output

```
21:36:48  + docker build -t --build-arg jar=tuya-message-listener-ecs-china.jar tas/tuya-message-listener:27 .
21:36:48  invalid argument "--build-arg" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format
21:36:48  See 'docker build --help'.
```

So where do I go wrong?

Comment: Can you share Jenkin's (and plugin's) version with us? This command works on my installation as intended (*Jenkins v2.235.5* and *docker pipeline plugin v1.24*)

Comment: I apologise, I know the problem now. It is taking the master branch Jenkinsfile which has the incorrect command, not the other branch jenkinsfile