# Error running docker build on jenkins slave

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have a jenkins master and able to pull in my code from CodeCommit. I have also set up a jenkins slave and this project has a Dockerfile that builds an image. When I try to execute the shell command,

```
docker build -f $WORKSPACE/BuildImage/docker/Dockerfile
```

I get the following error:

```
08:38:41 + docker build -f /opt/jenkins/workspace/Project/BuildImage/docker/Dockerfile
08:38:41 "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to provide the path/context.  So if it is the working directory

```
docker build -f $WORKSPACE/BuildImage/docker/Dockerfile .
```

Be sure to include the period(.) in the command.