# Unable to build docker image

Tags: docker

i want to build a docker image. I do this:

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile -t $IMAGE_TAG
```

I have this error:

> "docker build" requires exactly 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'.
>   Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | - Build an image from a
>   Dockerfile ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Comment: This question is already answered here.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ docker build -f Dockerfile -t $IMAGE_TAG .
```

The current directory dot `.` is missing at the end in your command line