# Why isn't docker recognizing my "-f" option?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

Following this post -- [docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help), I'm trying to build my docker image using a file with a non-traditional name ("local.Dockerfile") on Mac 10.13.6.  I tried the below

```
localhost:mydir davea$ docker build -t mycontainer -f local.Dockerfile 
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

But docker is choking on me.  I'm running version 19.03.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic command to build docker image:

```
docker build -t <image_tag> -f <Dockerfile_name> <Path_of_Dockerfile>
```

So you are missing to specify the path of your *local.Dockerfile* (which is mandatory). If your dockerfile is in the current directory from where you are running the command, then run below command, else update the path accordingly:

```
docker build -t mycontainer -f local.Dockerfile .
```

**Note:** You can specify the **Path_of_Dockerfile** in any way: relative path or absolute path, whichever way you feel comfortable.