# I already added ".", but "docker build" still requires exactly 1 argument

Tags: docker, docker-build

I tried several solutions, but I was not able to get any of them to work.

Here is my code:

```
jing-Inspiron-3670:~$ sudo docker build . -f ./dockerfile . -t mhcflurry:latest .
[sudo] password for jing: 
"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker build --help'.

Usage:  docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Build an image from a Dockerfile
```

Comment: You have too many dots. A `.` means "present or current directory", so you just need 1 at the end.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker: "build" requires 1 argument. See 'docker build --help'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28996907/docker-build-requires-1-argument-see-docker-build-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your flags, and the flag arguments, immediately after the `docker build` command.

Here is an example:

```
~/$ sudo docker build -f ./dockerfile -t mhcflurry:latest .
```